# MATLAB debug mode fails to display next line in command window

Tags: matlab, debugging

If you open a MATLAB `myfunction.m` file in the Editor, place some breakpoints, and type into the Command Window something like
`foo = myfunction(x,y)`

execution will pause at the breakpoint and the next executable line will be printed to the Command Window just above the `>>K` prompt.
 I've run into a strange case of an m-file which, when breakpoints are assigned, can be stepped thru just fine **but** the next-line text is not printed to the Command Window.

Try running the debugger with this file: [nanfastsmooth](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52688-nan-tolerant-fast-smooth) .

I've double-checked that any other m-file behaves as I'd expect in debug mode. For my files and this oddball file, other debugging ops work as expected - variable inspection, running commands at the prompt, using `F10` to step thru (and the green arrow in the editor window moves correctly), etc.   So what is going on?
MATLAB 2015a , windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: *"execution will pause at the breakpoint and **the next executable line will be printed to the Command Window just above the >>K prompt.**"*. Never seen this

Comment: Oh my mistake. It turns out that if you press "play", there is no printing. This is interesting, because when you press play, the `foo = myfunction(x,y)` line will indeed be printed in the command line as if it where the same thing as writing it. I always assumed that "play"'s behavior was just calling the command line, but I see that it is different.

Comment: I've never seen the next line printed when stepping, only when MATLAB enters the debugger.

Comment: @excaza   Matlab has entered the debugger at my breakpoint, and then I start stepping.

Comment: Yes, I understood the question.